# How do I set up a buy 1 get 2 free?

Tags: magento2, promotions

I have a set of products that I want to apply a buy one get two free with. The idea is that if they purchase one of the items within the set, they get 2 others within the item set for free.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your research or work you already done.

Answer (score 2):

[Link](https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-setup-buy-x-get-y-free-in-magento-2.html)

Follow the steps in above link.I hope it will help you.